# In spreadsheet (Excel or Google Sheets), how to find the sum of multiple values with multiple rows of column headers criteria?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, match, criteria

[image: Spreadsheet picture]

as in the above picture, I need to sum all the values within the table `C8:V22` which match

1. the first three characters of `column B`(orange),
2. `row 5` for the number(blue),
3. `row 6` for the first character(green),
4. `row 7` for the first three characters(yellow)

The desire result would be the sum of the number in red, which is 10001 + 10081 + 10161 + 10221 = `40464`

I tried many different ways to write the formula, one of that is:

```
=INDEX($B$5:$V$22,
  MATCH($D$26,LEFT($B$5:$B$90,3),0),
  MATCH(($F$26=$5:$5) * ($G$26=LEFT($6:$6, 1)) * (H26=LEFT($7:$7,3)), 0))
```

and pressed `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to make it as an array formula, but couldn't figure out where is the error.

Anyone could help on this? Thank you!

Edit: The following is a simplify table for easy reference:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | a1 | a2 | b1 |
|  | abc1 | abdf2 | abc2 |
| 111a | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 222a | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 111b | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 555a | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 333d | 23 | 24 | 25 |
| 111a | 26 | 27 | 28 |

in this case, the match values are `11` + `17` + `26` = `54`

I also tried using combinations of functions such as `SUMIFS`, `SUMPRODUCT`, `search`, e.t.c. but still not able figure out the solution.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: SUMIFS() or SUMPRODUCT() come to mind.

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike I also tried using combinations of these functions but not yet can figure out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sheet:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(B8:B22,3)=C26&"")*(C5:V5=E26)*(LEFT(C6:V6,1)=F26&"")*(LEFT(C7:V7,3)=G26&"")*C8:V22)
```

simply retrieve the sum using your parameters and converting in string to match exactly.

Comment: Thank you Terio, that works! What's the meaning of the `&""` in your formula?

Comment: @sam adding "" with & you trasform any value in text

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```vb
=LET(data,C8:V22,
   ruleColumnB,LEFT(B8:B22,LEN(D26))=TEXT(D26,"0"),
   ruleRow5,C5:V5=F26,
   ruleRow6, LEFT(C6:V6,1)=G26,
   ruleRow7, LEFT(C7:V7,3) =H26,
SUMPRODUCT(data*ruleColumnB*ruleRow5*ruleRow6*ruleRow7)
)
)
```

Using `LET` makes the formula more readable - esp. if you name the rules according to your special context.

If you don't have Excel 365 you have to replace the single parameters within `SUMPRODUCT` with each range/formula

Comment: I am using Excel 2019 so not able to use the `LET`. But by replacing the parameters in `SUMPRODUCT` with those range and formula, it works like a charm! While the way of using `LET` is more readable. Thank you